# How do you send a job acceptance email?

Tags: email, job-acceptance

I'm curious about the protocol here. If you are offered a  job and supposed to reply by email. When I looked online, I see stuff that looks like formal snail-mail letters, i.e [like this](http://www.whitesmoke.com/how-to-write-a-letter-of-acceptances.html):

```
Your First Name Your Last Name
Your address
Your phone number
Addressee's First Name Addressee's Last Name
Addressee's title/organization
Addressee's address

Dear Ms. Waters:

I was very happy to receive your phone call this afternoon when you offered me 
the position of head 6th grade teacher at the Children's Day School.  Please 
regard this letter as my formal acceptance.

As we agreed, my starting date will be August 24th, and I will work for the salary 
of $36,000 annually plus health coverage according to what we discussed.

Thank you again, Ms. Waters, for providing me with a wonderful opportunity.  Please
let me know if there is anything special I should do before my starting date.  I am
thrilled to be joining the Children's Day School team.

Sincerely,
Signature

First Name Last Name
Share With Your Friends!
```

But does it make sense to put one's name/address at the top of an email? For some reason I would rather just skip the header part, but at the same time I'm not sure of email-protocol. Also, this isn't the "formal" job acceptance exactly( although it is deemed as such).
any tips appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: Your example is definitely for a letter not an email. Was the offer verbal, an email, an emailed pdf, or package mailed to your home? Were there instructions? Did they want a signature?

Comment: The offer was emailed( ie emailed PDF, but  no request to scan & send signature)

Comment: @Adel - All you really need is to thank them for the offer, accept the offer, and some statement of how your looking forward to joining the company.  If you don't know about the post acceptance process request more information.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Until you receive a formal offer you can also be informal. But you need to be careful about what you include. Until you see the formal offer you don't want to commit to anything, or quit your old job.

I would just stick to the following format:

> Dear Ms. Waters:
>
> I was very happy to receive your email regarding the position of head 6th grade teacher at the Children's Day School.
>
> I look forward to hearing from you regarding any paperwork and required steps that need to be done prior to joining the company.
>
> Thank you again, Ms. Waters, for providing me with a wonderful opportunity.
>
> Sincerely,

Answer (score 4):

I would feel entirely comfortable to just send the body of the mail. For me, adding the formal bits (header etc) just seems very a-typical for email. In addition, you say that this mail is not necessarily something formal, so I would not feel inclined to be overly formal.